# How to give conditions to a loss functionin in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Say the model looks like this

```
inp = input()
feature = some_feature_layer()(inp)
out_1 = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(feature)
out_2 = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(feature)
```

What I want is to use the out_1 to weight the loss I use for out_2, which means the loss for out_2 should be something like

```
out_2_loss = out_1 * some_loss_function(y_true, out2)
```

I thought of writing the loss inside of the model, use the loss function as model output then simply increase/decrease the loss like this:

```
model = Model(inputs=[inp], outputs=[out_1, out_2_loss])
```

Then the problem becomes how to map different loss to different output. Is it possible to use a mapping like this in keras?

```
loss = {out_1 : 'binary_crossentropy',
out_2_loss : linear_function}
```

Comment: I know nothing about keras, but don't use `in` as a variable name because it's a keyword.

Comment: Sorry the problem was misleading. I changed it to inp now. I just laid the example too fast that I didn't notice it. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two approaches to mapping different losses to different outputs.

**Approach 1:** 
If output is named, use a dict mapping the names to the corresponding losses:

```
out1 = Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='binary_crossentropy')(x)
out2 = Dense(10, name='out2')(x)

model = Model(x, [out1, out2])
model.compile(loss={'binary_crossentropy': 'binary_crossentropy', 'out2': out_2_loss},
          optimizer='adam')
```

**Approach 2:** 
use a list of losses

```
model = Model(x, [out1, out2])
model.compile(loss=['binary_crossentropy', out_2_loss], optimizer='adam')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare special keywords as python variable like "in" here.
Try declaring some other variable name it will work out.

```
input_1 = input()
feature = some_feature_layer()(input_1)
out_1 = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(feature)
out_2 = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(feature)
out_2_loss = out_1 * some_loss_function(y_true, out2)
model = Model(inputs=[input_1], outputs=[out_1, out_2_loss])
loss = {out_1 : 'binary_crossentropy',out_2 : linear_function}
```

Comment: I just changed the problem. Sorry it was misleading. Is the loss part correct in this way then? I didn't try to use a dictionary to declare loss and that was the question.